# Loading up Ubuntu from a USB

Tags: usb, windows-8, boot-order

When I try to boot Ubuntu when it gives me a choice between Windows 8 and Ubuntu, it comes up with a screen that tells me to put in the Windows Installation Disc.  I started to use a USB.  I downloaded Ubuntu i3 onto the USB through pendrivelinux.  I have read that I need to switch my Boot Order so that the USB will boot instead of my hard drive.  I can't find that.  I've been told that the screen should say:

1. ODD
2. HDD
3. USB
4. LAN

I don't have a screen that resembles that.  In my BIOS I have a screen that shows a boot order as:

UEFI Boot Order
     OS Boot Manager
     Internal CD/DVD ROM Drive
     USB CD/DVD ROM Drive
     USB Diskette on Key/USB Hard Drive
     ! Network Adapter

I've read in places mentioning enabling Legacy Support.  But I don't want to do anything without some guidance here.  If anyone can help me in some way here, I would really appreciate it.  I am a beginner when it comes to this aspect of computers.

Answer (score 0):

Select USB Diskette or Key and it will do the job for you. I am also wondering whether you have loaded the BIOS or boot menu.